# CKEditor paste image upload

Tags: c#, .net, ckeditor

I've spent the last day trying to get an image pasted into CKEditor to automatically upload onto the web server.  I've been through several tutorials but most examples seem to be aimed toward PHP.  I tried CKFinder but it seems to complex for my needs.  Can someone point me toward the server-side code I need and the CKEditor configurations?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to paste image files, here's a way..

how about use another fileupload js plugin like [webuploader.js](https://github.com/fex-team/webuploader)?

webuploader.js can drag the image file to the dom to auto uploadfile

and then you can do something such as "appending to the ckeditor values" on CallbackSuccessUpload function;

```
uploader.on('uploadSuccess', function (file, response) {
        appendImageUrl(response);
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution is not useful.  The documentation you've liked to is in a foreign language.